# Parse #Error When Adding Formula with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having a really weird phenomenon happen in Google Sheets, and I've found nothing on this issue in my research.  I'm adding a query formula with javascript and getting a #Error on the sheet.  After quadruple checking I wasn't messing up the formula string (the first and most obvious thing to cause such an error) and satisfying myself that the formula was correct for syntax, I cut the formula from the formula bar, hit enter to make the cell blank, then pasted the formula I just cut back in, and boom.  Correct result, no error.  No change to the formula whatsoever.

So is the a bug with the script editor/sheet interaction?  Is a bug in Sheets?  Am I doing something wrong (can't imagine what)?

I even followed another post's suggestion and replaced the comma argument separator with a semicolon, but no change in behavior.  I have pasted the relevant code here, but I have also shared a Google sheet with the link below that demonstrates the issue.

To reproduce, follow these steps:

- Go to the sheet via the link below.
- Open Script Editor, and run the function "AddFormula"
- When the script runs it will add the formula shown below and you will see a #Error (parse error).
- Cut the formula from the formula bar on the sheet and press enter, creating the blank cell.
- Copy the formula you just cut back into the cell.  Here you will see the correct result of the formula displayed instead of the #Error.

For reference, the relevant code is here:

```
var wbID1 = "1tujKM_cAePTjBVS6q-gzGheSOAVz68vI0yi_LigCvyw";
var wb = SpreadsheetApp.openById(wbID1);  //The entire workbook.
var wsT = SpreadsheetApp.openById(wbID1).getSheetByName("TData");   //T=Target Worksheet

function AddFormula() {
  wsT.clear();
  wsT.getRange(2,1).setValue("AL");
  var TargetRange = wsT.getRange(2,1).getValue();
  var QueryString = "=QUERY(States!A2:E; \"Select D where B = '" + TargetRange + "'\")";
  wsT.getRange(2,3).setFormulaR1C1(QueryString);
}
```

The constructed formula in question resolves to:

```
=QUERY(States!A2:E, "Select D where B = 'AL'")
```

A demo sheet is here that reproduces the issue:
[Demo Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tujKM_cAePTjBVS6q-gzGheSOAVz68vI0yi_LigCvyw/edit?usp=sharing)

It would be great if there was a solution to this issue, but if that is too much to ask, I would love to simply be affirmed that I'm not crazy!  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Range.setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula), since your formula uses an A1 notation `States!A2:E`

If you use [Range.setFormulaR1C1(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformular1c1formula), the given formula must be in R1C1 notation.

Example: `=SUM(R[-3]C[0]:R[-1]C[0])`

---

**Your Code:**

```
function AddFormula() {
  wsT.clear();
  wsT.getRange(2,1).setValue("AL");
  var TargetRange = wsT.getRange(2,1).getValue();
  var QueryString = "=QUERY(States!A2:E; \"Select D where B = '" + TargetRange + "'\")";
  wsT.getRange(2,3).setFormula(QueryString);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Well I'll be...  I SWEAR I had switched to R1C1 specifically to try to troubleshoot this issue and thought that had no effect.  I never use R1C1 typically (because I work in code 99% of the time).  Whatever.  It worked.  Thank you, Ron!